# Make rasters have same size

Tags: r, raster

I have two rasters, one that is 43200x14760 cells and another that is 36000x12300 cells.  I want to make the smaller raster have the same number of cells as the larger one, but the disagg() function only takes integers.  How can I make these the same size without making huge rasters based on the LCM of their dimensions.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for help on how to improve your question and increase your chances of getting help

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the [matchResolution](https://rdrr.io/github/mqueinnec/foster/man/matchResolution.html) function of the [foster](https://rdrr.io/github/mqueinnec/foster/) package. I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).